# Remove some special HTMLs from one Persian string in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have s VERY simple question, ALSO i found No code working for my String !

I have converted a simple text to another string with `strip_tags` function.

And now i have this string :

```
&lt;b&gt;مرتبط با :&lt;/b&gt;&lt;b&gt; &lt;span&gt;&lt;span&gt;داداشم موهاش فره نمیدونم چرا میخوابه دوبرابر میشه اصن یه چیز &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;#13; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;span&gt;وحشتناک.دیشب رفتم دستشویی برگشتم پام گیر کرد به پتوش تو خواب &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;#13; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;span&gt;وبیداری افتادم روش یه آن با اون موهاش یه داد کشید چنان ترسناک شد &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;#13; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;spa
```

How can i remove bad characters like : `&lt;/b&gt;&lt;b&gt` & ....

How can i do it ?

**MY code is Persian** , SO , I need a code to support Persian and UTF8.

I also tried this code :

```
$des = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.-\s]/", "", $des);
```

But i get no persian charackters because it works with English !

How can i remove them ?

Comment: i would do `html_decode`, then `strip_tags`.

Comment: The persian regex is: \x{0600}-\x{06FF}]*$

Comment: @Templar tnx, Is there any good way for me to return that persian string ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just convert back the HTML entities to characters with `htmlspecialchars_decode`, then strip them out with `strip_tags`:

```
$your_string = "&lt;b&gt;مرتبط با :&lt;/b&gt;&lt;b&gt; &lt;span&gt;&lt;span&gt;داداشم موهاش فره نمیدونم چرا میخوابه دوبرابر میشه اصن یه چیز &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;#13; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;span&gt;وحشتناک.دیشب رفتم دستشویی برگشتم پام گیر کرد به پتوش تو خواب &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;#13; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;span&gt;وبیداری افتادم روش یه آن با اون موهاش یه داد کشید چنان ترسناک شد &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;#13; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;span&gt;&lt;spa";
$result = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode($your_string));
echo "<pre>" . $result . "</pre>";
```

Results:

> مرتبط با : داداشم موهاش فره نمیدونم چرا میخوابه دوبرابر میشه اصن یه چیز 
>    وحشتناک.دیشب رفتم دستشویی برگشتم پام گیر کرد به پتوش تو خواب 
>    وبیداری افتادم روش یه آن با اون موهاش یه داد کشید چنان ترسناک شد

Edit: PHPFiddle link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g3hc-f8vr